# Cannot Store Instagram API access_token with PHP

Tags: php, api, oauth, access-token

I'm working on building a small web app connecting into the instagram API. Currently using [this library on GitHub](https://github.com/macuenca/Instagram-PHP-API) which makes things a bit easier. I can connect and initially login fine, and the page will display all user data.

But once you refresh the page all the data is lost, and it appears the script can't find my access token anymore. I tried storing this into a PHP session variable - but maybe I'm doing the whole process incorrectly? I just want to keep the same user session throughout an entire website once the OAuth is performed.

You can check out the small app live here: http://spyrestudios.com/demos/instagram-api/index.php

Additionally my callback URL is http://spyrestudios.com/demos/instagram-api/instagammy.php - this is the script which will work right after you connect. But try refreshing the page and all the data is gone! Also here is my bit of code which *should use the library to store the current user's access token:

```
session_start();
require_once 'Instagram.php'; // the library code
$config = array(
    'client_id' => 'f0d225aa955c4bd9ae563f87f831efab', // Your client id
    'client_secret' => '377b77afc1274a89bd2df7d77e934689', // Your client secret
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://spyrestudios.com/demos/instagram-api/instagammy.php', // The redirect URI you provided when signed up for the service
 );
// Instantiate the API handler object
$instagram = new Instagram($config);
$accessToken = $instagram->getAccessToken();
$_SESSION['InstagramAccessToken'] = $accessToken;
```

Really struggling for a solution, so I'd appreciate any help I can get. Willing to post examples of my code if needed..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean that the data you getting from the OAuth system is getting lost?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi yes it seems that way. After you first log in all the data is pulled just fine - but if you refresh the page, or go to a new page and hit "back" everything is lost. I've stored the token as a session variable which I thought would keep it active until the user logged out but maybe I'm approaching this wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have already looks fine (although I have no experience in Instagram), assuming that $accessToken is actually being stored correctly in the session.

But surely at some point you need to feed back in $accessToken so that it can be verified.  Like I said, I've not used Instagram before, so I don't know how you would do this.

Comment: Yes is this where the secret token comes in? I have been looking through Instagram's API docs and I can't find info anywhere. I may try setting a cookie and see if this works instead.

Comment: Whether you store to token in a session data or a cookie is irrelevant.  The point is, at some point you'ere going to have to feed back in the token to authenticate the user, otherwise you may as well not store it.  The whole point of access tokens is to verify a user across a website, without asking them to "login" each time a page loads.  At the moment you've got the "logging in part" right, but there's no way yet to verify the user once he/she moves to a different page- that's what the token is for.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you still care..

The problem is that refreshing is hitting the oauth landing page again when you refresh or back, but there is no authorization for it to collect the information from.  In theory you could just wrap your setting of the session variable around a check:

```
$instagram = new Instagram($config);
$accessToken = $instagram->getAccessToken();
if ($accessToken != '')
    $_SESSION['InstagramAccessToken'] = $accessToken;
```

That would stop an unwanted to call to your oauth landing page from clearing the current session value.

But better still would be to have the landing page redirect to a different page for the display.  ie have your instagammy.php end there and add a

```
header("Location: http://spyrestudios.com/demos/instagram-api/dosomethinghere.php");
die();
```

That way the user won't ever see the "instagammy.php" page in their history and won't be able to go back to it.

Comment: Thanks I do still care as this was bugging me quite a bit. I appreciate your response it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

This work for me, instead the original file instagammy.php

```
$instagram = new Instagram($config);
if ($_SESSION['InstagramAccessToken'] == ''){
    $accessToken = $instagram->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['InstagramAccessToken'] = $accessToken;
}else{
    $accessToken = $_SESSION['InstagramAccessToken'];
    $instagram->setAccessToken($_SESSION['InstagramAccessToken']);
}
```